# Why is react throwing npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm building a front end for a website with a lot of photos in react. Probably half or one third of the time I run npm start I get this error:

```
class FastBuffer extends Uint8Array {}
^

RangeError: Array buffer allocation failed
    at new ArrayBuffer (<anonymous>)
    at new Uint8Array (<anonymous>)
    at new FastBuffer (internal/buffer.js:951:1)
    at createUnsafeBuffer (buffer.js:152:12)
    at Function.allocUnsafeSlow (buffer.js:397:10)
    at read (C:\Users\workspace\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\serialization\FileMiddleware.js:562:32)
    at C:\Users\workspace\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\serialization\FileMiddleware.js:622:7
    at C:\Users\workspace\frontend\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:343:16
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:180:23)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-23T23_31_45_511Z-debug.log
```

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.13
3 info using node@v14.17.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~prestart: frontend@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: frontend@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\workspace\frontend\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\mingw64\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16\bin;C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin;C:\Users\Downloads\gradle-7.0-bin\gradle-7.0\bin;C:\Users\Downloads\apache-maven-3.8.1-bin\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2;C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts;C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37;C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Users\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.1\bin;C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
9 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\workspace\frontend
10 silly lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: frontend@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:376:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:376:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid frontend@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\workspace\frontend
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19043
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v14.17.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.13
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error frontend@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I have tried clearing the cache, as well as running npm install again.
I have no way of reliably reproducing this result. Sometimes it happens sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes it happens right when i run npm start, sometimes it happens five minutes later. How can I solve this, and what is the core problem?

Comment: Where is the source code?

Comment: What code do you need to see? The project is 1.5 GB, I definitely can't upload all the source code.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I just upgraded to CRA 5 and Webpack 5. Mine server starts fine, but a few minutes later I will get this error, crashing it. My line numbers in FileMiddleware are a bit different from yours, so we probably have slightly different versions.

I definitely did not have this problem back on CRA/Webpack 4

Answer (score 1):

The question is generic and without having more context, it is hard to answer the question correctly. But, this error -

```sh
class FastBuffer extends Uint8Array {}
^

RangeError: Array buffer allocation failed
```

might occur in case of not enough memory. Can you please confirm that you have enough space and if your project has mentioned minimum system requirements then you're fulfilling it?